# Writing Data via COM Port to a legacy Software?

Tags: c++, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, visual-studio-2019, com-port

[Block Diagramm attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mSbn.jpg)

This is my first question here.

My problem is, that I have to send data to a `legacy Software` via `COM Port`. I receive the data over Bluetooth LE from a peripheral device and have to transmit the data on my receiving PC to the `COM Port` for the legacy Software to read.
Here starts the trouble: I can't write the data to the COM Port and connect my Software, because the COM Port can only be opened once.
What i already did is:
I installed `com0com` and paired two ports. That worked for testing, but i need to implement this in my own Code.
I know there is an example in `WDK` for creating virtual Serial ports, but sadly that is not working at all.

Any suggestions?

I am working with `C++` and

```
visual Studio 2019
```

Thanks for help !!

Comment: What app opens the com port initially ? Open it with FILE_SHARE_READ.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer!
I wrote an app, that receives the data on the PC, opens a COM Port and writes the data. The Legacy Software tries to open a COM Port too. 
When i open the COM Port with FILE_SHARE_READ or _WRITE, it makes no difference. This option is only for Filestreams and cant be used for serial Ports.

Comment: Yes it can be used for serial ports.

Comment: I open the COM Port like this:
`hSerial = CreateFile(L"COM6",
  FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
  0,
  0,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
  0); `
And write the data like this:
`WriteFile(hSerial, pCharValueBuffer->Data, pCharValueBuffer->DataSize, &BytesWritten, NULL);`
but i still cant open the same port via hterm or my legacy software

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Have you tried it out with Serial ports? If yes please tell me, what else i have to do. Btw: I cant Access the Legacy Software to Change the reading method. Only in my Code the writing method. Is that enough?

Comment: no, all the apps have to use FILE_SHARE_READ for the opening to succeed.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use com0com? Then, as a mere idea, for example, physically add a USB serial converter and realize the mechanism of com0com in hardware?

Comment: I need a software solution for this issue. I cant Use additional software or ugly hardware workarounds because its an update for ourcompanies software. Im adding new functionality.

Comment: It's hard to understand with just text, but are you trying to do something that is not possible with just application programs? You may need a device driver such as com0com, or at least a program like a hook routine to insert into the driver stack called a filter driver. Add a diagram to your question that graphically describes what software/hardware you have and what features you need, or com0com is open source so you can look it up and extract ideas How about transplanting to?

Comment: @kunif Thx for your answer! I added a diagramm of my setup, i quickly made it in paint, sry for that. I know its not possible with just an application program. com0com is opensource, but i failed to get the code with CVS, it just cant connect to the server. Maybe it got deleted? The com0com code i found elsewhere online is not commented and really hard to read without guidance.

Comment: Is it Source-forge [Null-modem emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/)? It seems that there are few comments. For example, it's still unclear if it works, but something like [Simple Serial Port Monitor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311159/SIMPLE-SERIAL-PORT-MONITOR) may be helpful.

Comment: @kunif yes it is the Null-modem emulator.
maybe there is another way to put data in a comport? ive never written a Driver and i failed to create a virtual driver with the wdk sample.

Comment: I can't give any advice because I don't have experience or knowledge, but such a material may be helpful. [User-mode device stacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/device-nodes-and-device-stacks#user-mode-device-stacks), [COM port redirector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector). An additional link, perhaps a helpful, still usable serial port logger. [eltima-software/RS232-Data-Logger](https://github.com/eltima-software/RS232-Data-Logger)

Comment: Sadly these link are not helpful to my issue, but i really appreciate your help!